# Getting an error message "Method range of Object_'Global Failed'", the code is not picking the corect Value

Tags: vba, excel

Just want to check whether value in file Nilesh micro is present in B2C tool, for that i have created macro, it is not picking correct value.

```
Sub find()

Workbooks("B2C_Tool.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False

    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

        LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Workbooks("Nilesh Micro.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

        On Error Resume Next
        For Repeat = 2 To 47
            With Range("A" & Repeat)
                If Range("A" & Repeat).Value = Range(LR & "L") Then

                Else
                    MsgBox ("Need To Add in the List")

                End If
            End With
        Next Repeat

    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Please can you help on this.

Answer (score 1):

First, in order for your code to run, both `Workbooks` : "B2C_Tool.xlsm" , and "Nilesh Micro.xlsm" need to be Open.

Second, in your code you have the first `With ActiveSheet` referring to "Sheet1" in "B2C_Tool.xlsm" workbook, but 4 lines below you are activating "Sheet2" in "Nilesh Micro.xlsm". This will result all statements below to refer to "Sheet2" as the reference object.

That's why it's better to avoid using `Activate`, `ActiveSheet` and use referenced objects instead.

There is no need to use the `With Range("A" & Repeat)` with the purpose of your code, and lastly `Range(LR & "L")` will raise an error, it should be either `Range("L" & LR)` , or you can use `Cells(LR, "L")`.

The code below will fix all your errors, but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve ?

**Question**: The last section checks every cell in Column A in "Sheet2" (in "Nilesh Micro.xlsm" workbook) and compares it with the value at the last row in "Sheet1" in "B2C_Tool.xlsm" workbook ? is that the purpose ? to show a `MsgBox` every time these values are not the same ?

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub find()

Dim LR As Long, Repeat As Long

With Workbooks("B2C_Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    If .AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False

    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Repeat = 2 To 47
        If Workbooks("Nilesh Micro.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Repeat).Value = .Range("L" & LR).Value Then
            ' you are not doing anything in tour code if the IF criteria is met ??
        Else
            MsgBox ("Need To Add in the List")
        End If
    Next Repeat    

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I m looking for Value in "A" column of Nilesh Micro and find the value in Column "L" in a B2C Tool, for all the values I got the message "Need To Add in the List".

Comment: @NileshPawar cause this is what you had in your code, what do you want to have ? what are you trying to find ?

Comment: For Missing Value

Comment: @NileshPawar I think you mean you want to compare each value in Column A in "Sheet2" and see if it exits in the entire column L in "Sheet1" in "B2C_Tool.xlsm" , am I correct ?